# How do I find commands matching a set of filters with Get-Command?

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to powershell. I've done searches and checked stackoverflow and super user. Even my mobile app and affordable textbook say nothing of it.

Is there an easy way to apply multiple options / filters that I don't understand. Or is there a term that I don't know of that means options / filters?

I've been trying to use:

```
get-command -commandtype cmdlet -and -verb add
get-command -commandtype cmdlet| -verb add
get-command -commandtype cmdlet|get-command -verb add
```

None of these bring back the proper list. And the last brings back something but it is always random and only some of the proper results.

I'd be interested in any response. Very interested if you are a great powershell user that could simply and concisely help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-Command -Verb Add
```

would show you all cmdlets *and* functions whose name starts with `Add-`.

If you want to limit the output to cmdlets only, use wildcard pattern `Add-*` with the (implied) `-Name` parameter instead:

```
Get-Command -CommandType cmdlet Add-*
```

A less efficient, pipeline-based equivalent would be:

```
Get-Command -CommandType cmdlet | ? Verb -eq 'Add' # '?' is an alias for 'Where-Object'
```

---

While it would make sense to be able to combine `-CommandType` with the *specific value* of `Cmdlet` with a `-Verb` argument, the current syntax (as of PSv5.1) doesn't permit that, as evidenced by (part of) the output from `Get-Command -?`:

```
Get-Command [[-Name] <String[]>] [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]>] [-All] [-CommandType {Alias | Function | Filter | Cmdlet | ExternalScript | Application | 
Script | Workflow | Configuration | All}] [-FullyQualifiedModule <ModuleSpecification[]>] [-ListImported] [-Module <String[]>] [-ParameterName <String[]>] 
[-ParameterType <PSTypeName[]>] [-ShowCommandInfo] [-Syntax] [-TotalCount <Int32>] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Command [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]>] [-All] [-FullyQualifiedModule <ModuleSpecification[]>] [-ListImported] [-Module <String[]>] [-Noun <String[]>] 
[-ParameterName <String[]>] [-ParameterType <PSTypeName[]>] [-ShowCommandInfo] [-Syntax] [-TotalCount <Int32>] [-Verb <String[]>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Each paragraph above represents a so-called *parameter set*, and as you can see, `-Verb` and `-Name` are in *different* parameter sets, which means you can't use them as part of the same command line.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `get-command -commandtype cmdlet -and -verb add`

  - Commands take a *list* of parameters (parameter values) - the interpretation of which is up to the target command; there is no support for using Boolean operators (such as `-and`) to combine these.
    Boolean operators can only be used in *expressions*, not in *commands*.
- `get-command -commandtype cmdlet| -verb add`

  - You can only use a pipeline to pipe to *commands* (cmdlets, functions, aliases, external utilities and their arguments) - in your case, `-verb` is interpreted as a command name, which obviously fails.
- `get-command -commandtype cmdlet|get-command -verb add`

  - One you've used `get-command -commandtype cmdlet` to retrieve all cmdlets, you don't need a 2nd `get-command` instance to further filter the results - instead, you filter by the *properties* of the *objects* output by the 1st `get-command` call, as demonstrated above.

Comment: Outstanding. Powershell is definitely different, but this seems obtainable.